# How do I calculate the force applied on an inner surface of a tube?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

[image]

This is a one piece button.

the point in the middle is not necessarly the center, and the r1,r2,r3 are not necessarly the radius . d- is the shank between the button and the middle point.

How do I guarantee that when I apply Force (F1) on the yellow button,I will get a homogenous spread of Force (F2) on the surface?
for example, If I need F2= 4 Newton, and I can control everything else, what would be the best soluttion ?

Comment: I don't understand what this mechanism is. What are the black and red parts? What is the cylinder? Is the black thing solid? Are the F2 forces acting on the red thing? What is this device and why is it important that the forces spread in all directions equally?

Comment: the black is a solid material - PMMA.  The red part is a sensor on the inner surface the senses the force. the cylnder is PMMA - the right picture is cross sectional upper view of the part marked. F2 is the force that needs to be sensed by the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to guarantee that the force is the same magnitude in all directions is to replace the PMMA with a liquid in a flexible container. Otherwise, if you use a hard plastic for both parts, the force on the red part will be concentrated on the points where the red and black parts make contact. It is impossible to perfectly machine solid parts to be perfectly mating, so distributing the force uniformly is impossible. A liquid, on the other hand, will have the same pressure everywhere within itself, so the force on its surface will be uniform as well.